# Website failover across internet connections

Tags: high-availability, failover, internet

**Requirement**

For a network having 4 static IP internet leased line connections linked to hosting a website.

What are the current strategies one can apply to ensure high availability in case of internet failure of one of the connections ?

If this is possible, How ?

```
nslookup sampleWebsite.com

Server:  sampleWebsite.com
Address:  111.111.111.11

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    sampleWebsite.com
Addresses:111.111.111.11
          222.222.222.22
          333.333.333.33
          444.444.444.44
```

[image]

**Setup**
Server - Windows Server 2012
Internet connection - Standard Fibre-optic 4Mbps connection
Firewall - Commercial firewall appliance

**Note**
Tried [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) & [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), but couldn't find a similar question

**Similar, but are they the solution ?**
[Why is DNS failover not recommended?](https://serverfault.com/questions/60553/why-is-dns-failover-not-recommended)
[How browsers handle multiple IPs](https://serverfault.com/questions/327708/how-browsers-handle-multiple-ips)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only reliably have the DNS point at one IP, as you will know from reading about DNS failover.

You need to either have your ISP implement a routing protocol to distribute the incoming connections to an active line (such as with BGP) or use an external service which decides which is an active connection (such as load balancing or dynamic DNS)

My suggestions would be Amazon Route 53 (http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) for DNS based on health-checks or something like CloudFlare (https://www.cloudflare.com/overview) which adds a layer between your users and your site